# Problema con una tarea en curso de Python

Tags: python, bucles

tengo un ejercicio que consta en lo siguiente:
Crear una lista interactiva en la que el programa pide al usuario números (hasta insertar un número de salida (en este caso -9999), luego el programa elimine los números repetidos e imprima la lista sin ningún número repetido. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
miLista = []
numExit = -9999

while True:
    numero = int(input("Ingrese un numero, o ingrese -9999 para finalizar: "))
    if numero == numExit:
        break
    else:
        miLista.append (numero)
        print (miLista)
        numero = int(input("Ingrese otro numero, o ingrese -9999 para finalizar: "))
        print (miLista)

for i in miLista:
    if miLista[i] == miLista[i]:
        del miLista[i]

print("La lista solo con elementos únicos:")
print(miLista)
```

Ya intenté cambiar cambiar de lugar el if y ponerlo al final del ciclo while e igual no funciona, trate de buscar la solucion codificando en papel y checkeando asi los pasos y me sigue pareciendo que esta bien pero en el vsc no funciona como en mi cabeza o el papel

nota: cuando pongo el if despues del 2do input, funciona pero con un ingreso de delay y cuando el codigo tiene que pasar a la segunda parte (al ciclo for) me dice que el ciclo esta fuera de rango (cuando ese mismo fragmento me funciona bien en otros 2 ejercicios, para encontrar y eliminar números repetidos), alguna solución o propuesta para el programa?

Soy nuevo en esto y es mi primera pregunta aqui, muchas gracias por la ayuda desde ya! saludos

Comment: Claro que la lista está fuera de rango. Digamos que tienes una lista de 10 elementos, y empiezas a recorrerla con `for i in miLista`, ese bucle va a recorrer los **10** elementos, ojo, 10. A la segunda iteración te encuentras un repetido, así que lo eliminas... ahora tu lista tiene solo 9 elementos, pero tu bucle cuantos va a intentar recorrer? Exacto, **10**! No puedes eliminar elementos de una lista mientras la recorres, lo que deberías hacer es comprobar si está repetido *ANTES* de insertarlo

Comment: Te agradezco mucho Benito, entiendo tu explicacion pero no logro encontrar una solución, me esta costando mucho conjugar el ciclo "for" (que de por si me cuesta mucho) con las listas, que me parece relativamente sencillo pero a al momento de ponerlas a interactuar con ciclos siempre tropiezo, supongo que tengo que repasar todo de nuevo o buscar alguna fuente extra de estudio para comprenderlo mejor. Te agradezco mucho tu colaboracion

Answer (score 0):

Como te comentaron, esto está mal:

```
for i in miLista:
...
        del miLista[i]
```

No se debe alterar una estructura sobre la que se está iterando. En este caso necesitas **si o si** una lista temporal en la que se harán alteraciones. Adicional hay inconsistencias en los input, hay dos capturas de datos. Hice una modificación en esa parte. Igual, puedes modificarlo para que salga con -9999 como lo tenías.

```
miLista = []

while True:
    numero = input("Ingrese un numero, o en blanco para finalizar: ")
    if numero == '':
        break
    miLista.append(int(numero))
    print(miLista)

sin_repetir = []
for i in miLista:
    if i not in sin_repetir:
        sin_repetir.append(i)
miLista = sin_repetir # Sobreescribe la lista original con el resultado

print("La lista solo con elementos únicos:")
print(miLista)
```

Obviamente la forma más sencilla de hacer esta operación es convertir la lista en set y luego regresarla a lista, pero supongo que debías hacerlo manualmente. En todo caso, una vez capturados los datos:

```
miLista = list(set(miLista)) # Lista sin valores repetidos.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano por responder! Al parecer noto 2 inconsistencias en la solucion que me brindaste, 1) Cuando intento salir del ciclo con el espacio en blanco, me surge el error de "invalid literal for int()", pero cuando lo cambio a -9999 nuevamente, el programa lo incorpora a la lista y no sale como deberia hacer con el break :S

Comment: ¿Qué versión de python estás usando @FacundoZavaleta ? Con la 3.x, en mi caso 3.9, funciona perfectamente, puedes [verlo en vivo acá](https://www.onlinegdb.com/IZddAgl64V). Si estás usando python 2.7 o menor recomiendo actualices la versión que está obsoleta y sin soporte desde hace 2 años. En todo caso, solo tendrías que cambiar `input` por `raw_input` y ya se arregla.

Comment: Estoy usando la version 3.9 en el VSC, acabo de entrar al link que me enviaste y me da el mismo problema: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '", y tambien cuando lo cambio a -9999, el programa lo incluye en la lista y no se sale. Respecto al raw_input, aun no lo tengo visto en el curso. Gracias por seguir respondiendo.